# How do the Server Extensions work in X?

Tags: linux, x11

Let's take an example. When I run:

> xkbprint $DISPLAY keyboard.ps

what happens in the system? I would like to know how the X really work because I regularly get nasty error reports such as

> Fatal Error:      Cannot load geometry for /tmp/launch-NawGIk/:0
>
> ```
>              Exiting
> ```

I know that the X11 was designed in a way that it is easy to extend. But how? How does the X11 protocol work? How do the X extensions work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever happens, I'm pretty certain it isn't going to be what you expect.

The syntax of [xkbprint(1](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xkbprint.1.html)) is

> $ xkbprint *sourcefile* *destfile*

and *sourcefile* should be a compiled xkb file.  `$DISPLAY` is going to resolve to something like `mymachine:0.0`, which isn't a very reasonable file name.

Actually, since you're running a Mac, it's *echoing* exactly what it's seeing: `/tmp/launch-NawGIk/:0` is the special OS/X magic to let *launchd* run X apps.  The error message means that it's not finding a geometry or display *in that file*.  Which is no surprise since there *is* no file named `/tmp/launch-NawGIk/:0

Try reading the man page, and see if you don't have more luck with a compiled .xkm file.

More generally, if you want a starting introduction to X, [try this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4879).

Comment: My man xkbprint says: "The source can be any compiled keymap (.xkm) file that includes a geometry description or an  X  display  specification. ". He should probably express his display specification more precisely to remove confusion with file path.

Comment: No, that display spec is exactly the Mac standard.  That lets launchd interpret the "file path" as a display for X; it results in launchd starting an X server if none is running.

Answer (score 2):

Man xkbprint says:

> The  xkbprint  comman generates a
>   printable or encapsulated PostScript
>   description of the XKB keyboard
>   description specified by source. The
>   source can be any compiled keymap
>   (.xkm) file that includes a geometry
>   description or an  X  display 
>   specification.

As Charlie Martin pointed out, xkbprint is misusing your $DISPLAY as a file name. Try specifying the display more precisely, to avoid ambiguity with file name. Try man xhost. Maybe passing simple ":0" will fix the problem?